# jQuery change text in div using the "data" attribute

Tags: jquery

In jQuery Tabs UI, I'm using this function (thanks to SO'ers) to change the CSS of a div in order to show a particular image according to the data-image attribute of the active tab.

**Function:**

```
var img = $(ui.panel).data("image");
$("#headerwrapper")
.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, function() {
$(this).css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")")
.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
});
}
```

**HTML and CSS:**

html in the tabs structure:

```
<div id="home" data-image="/images/water.jpg">tab content</div

<div id="about" data-image="/images/office.jpg">tab content</div>

  ...more tabs...
```

css (water.jpg is default when no data-image is present):

```
#headerwrapper {background: url(images/water.jpg);}
```

So I can correctly credit the photographer when their image is shown: how would I change that function (see below) in order to use a corresponding data attribute called credit to change the text of  with the active tab? And can one have two different data attributes in the html? Or is there a better way?

**Function:**

```
var img = $(ui.panel).data("credit");
$("#headerwrapper")
.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, function() {

$(this).css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")") //what goes here in order
                                                    //change data-credit
                                                    //in the div photocredit?
.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
});
}
```

**HTML:**  in the tabs structure:

```
<div id="home" data-image="/images/water.jpg" data-credit="Photog1">tab content</div

<div id="about" data-image="/images/office.jpg" data-credit="Photog2">tab content</div>

      ...more tabs...
```

In the site footer (outside of #headerwrapper) :

```
<div id="photocredit"></div>
```

And, what is the CSS for #photocredit? Just this: `#photocredit {}`

Comment: won't this work > `#("#photocredit").html(img);`

Comment: I'm not calling an image, but text in another div.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attr` function to change the attribute of `div` tag:

```
$(this).attr("data-credit", "Photographer...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to set the photocredit

Example Here: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/VhvvG/

modified jQuery:

```
var $home = $('#home');

$('#headerwrapper').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle'
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + $home.data('image') + ")").animate({
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }).children('#photocredit').html($home.data('credit')); // set the photo credit from data-credit attribute to the child element #photocredit
});
```

---

I'm assuming the `<div id="photocredit"></div>` is a child element of `<div id="headerwrapper"...` element, if it isn't then do something like

```
$('#headerwrapper').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle'
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + $home.data('image') + ")").animate({
        opacity: 'toggle'
    })
});
$('#photocredit').html($home.data('credit')); // set the photo credit from data-credit attribute to the child element #photocredit
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close, but I neglected to say that I have multiple tabs with mutliple images - one image for each tab - and so I edited the code above. So the addition to the function has to grab the active tab, like the original function, and show the data "credit" for each active tab.